# Explicit calculation of spin connection through Cartan's first structure equation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

Given the metric 
$$
ds^2 = F(r)^2dr^2 + r^2d\theta^2 + r^2 \sin^2(\theta)\,  d\phi^2, 
$$
I'm trying to find the corresponding spin connections $\omega^a_{\ b}$ using the first structure equation:
$$
de + \omega e = 0. 
$$
I found the vielbeins $e$ and their exterior derivatives $de$: 
$$ 
de^1 = 0, \quad de^2 = drd\theta, \quad de^3 = sin(\theta)drd\phi + r\cos(\theta)d\theta d\phi,
$$
but I am stuck on actually working out the $\omega$. 
I read through Zee's 'GR in a nutshell', and he does the same calculation but just says: "In general, write $\omega^a_{\,b} = \omega^a_{\,bc}e^c = \omega^a_{\,b\mu}dx^\mu$. Plug this into the first structure equation and match terms. How do I actually go about calculating $\omega^1_{\, 2}$, $\omega^1_{\, 3}$, and $\omega^2_{\, 3}$ at this point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have, the first step is to identify $e^r = F(r)\mathrm{d}r, e^\theta = r\mathrm{d}\theta$ and $e^\phi = r\sin \theta \mathrm{d}\phi$. The trick is to then take the derivatives but *re-express them in terms of $e$ again*. Thus,

$$\mathrm{d}e^r = 0, \quad \mathrm{d}e^\theta = -\mathrm{d\theta} \wedge \mathrm{d}r = -\frac{1}{rF(r)}e^\theta \wedge e^r$$

and,

$$\mathrm{de^\phi} = -\sin\theta \mathrm{d\phi} \wedge \mathrm{d}r - r\cos\theta \mathrm{d}\phi \wedge \mathrm{d}\theta = -\frac{1}{rF(r)} e^\phi \wedge e^r - \frac{\cot \theta}{r^2} e^\phi \wedge e^\theta.$$

Now let's take an example of using Cartan's first equation. We have $\mathrm{d}e^a + \omega^a_b \wedge e^b = 0$ and if we choose $a=\theta$ the equations read,

$$\frac{1}{rF(r)}e^\theta \wedge e^r = \omega^\theta_r \wedge e^r + \omega^\theta_\theta \wedge e^\theta + \omega^\theta_\phi \wedge e^\phi.$$

We have $\omega^\theta_\theta = 0$ by anti-symmetry. We can identify now $\omega^\theta_r = -\omega^r_\theta = \frac{1}{rF(r)}e^\theta$. Notice the last term we could choose $\omega^\theta_\phi = 0$ however Cartan's equations are a system of equations, so we are not free to make this choice yet without considering the other equations. We can at best say $\omega^\theta_\phi$ is proportional to $\mathrm{d}\phi$ to ensure $\omega^\theta_\phi \wedge e^\phi = 0$. As it turns out, we don't have $\omega^\theta_\phi = 0$ because of the $a = \phi$ equation, which will give you $\omega^\theta_\phi = -r^{-2}\cot\theta\, e^\phi$.

I hope this elucidates how to use Cartan's structure equation. Computing the Ricci tensor is then much simpler, as rather than solving for components you're just plugging in and computing.

Answer (score 2):

There is also an explicit procedure that is often better if the vielbein is simple.

We have $$ \mathrm d e^a=-\frac{1}{2}C^a_{bc}e^b\wedge e^c, $$ where the $C^a_{bc}$ are the vielbein commutators. We can invert the first structure equation explicitly as $$ 0=\mathrm de^a+\omega^a_{\ b}\wedge e^b \\ =-\frac{1}{2}C^a_{bc}e^b\wedge e^c+\omega^a_{c\ b}e^c\wedge e^b \\ \frac{1}{2}C^a_{bc}e^b\wedge e^c=\frac{1}{2}\left( \omega^a_{b\ c}-\omega^a_{c\ b} \right)e^b\wedge e^c, $$ so $$ C^a_{bc}=\omega^a_{b\ c}-\omega^a_{c\ b}. $$

Lowering the index, we get $$ C_{a,bc}=\omega_{b,ac}-\omega_{c,ab} \\ C_{b,ca}=\omega_{c,ba}-\omega_{a,bc} \\ -C_{c,ab}=-\omega_{a,cb}+\omega_{b,ca}, $$ now sum these up: $$ C_{a,bc}+C_{b,ca}-C_{c,ab}=2\omega_{c,ba} \\ \omega_{c,ab}=\frac{1}{2}\left(C_{c,ab}-C_{a,bc}-C_{b,ca}\right) \\ \omega_{ab}=\frac{1}{2}\left(C_{c,ab}-C_{a,bc}-C_{b,ca}\right)e^c. $$

If the veilbein is simple, then the $\mathrm de^a=-\frac{1}{2}C^a_{bc}e^b\wedge e^c$ will only involve a few terms at most, and the spin connection is very easy to calculate from this.

Comment: Looks like both our methods are relatively equal in terms of simplicity - if the vielbein is simple, as you said, in the first method solving the linear system is also trivial.

Comment: @JamalS Not to me :) . But I guess this is highly subjective. For vielbeins like the natural FLRW or Schwarzschild vielbeine I find this method simpler and easier. But that's me.